# Channel form not redirecting

Tags: safecracker

After upgraded from 3.5.5 to 5.1.3 .. Channel Form doesn't return..
I tested with very simple code.. like

```
{exp:channel:form channel="form_test" return="inscription/merci"}
<div class="row" id="inscription">

    <div class="column small-6">
        <label for="nom">Nom <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" required=""  name="title" id="title" value="" aria-required="true">
    </div>


<button  name="submit" type="submit" class="button expanded">SEND</button>
</div>
{/exp:channel:form}
```

I also tried to put these template in an other template group.. but i always get a white page after submiting.. Still the  channel form is submited as i can see the new entry in CP..

But then i tried on an other EE install (other site with 5.1.3 from 4.x).. and it works!?

Comment: Turn on error reporting so the white page actually tells you something.

Comment: It's already ON.. i see nothing..

Comment: My mistake.. i created a extension in EE 3.. then in ee 5 it's not working!..  If i uninstall my Addon.. it's working fine..